# Android expandablelistview can not display the last group when expanded

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview, android-webview, expandablelistview

I'm trying to implement a FAQ screen in my project and I wanted to use ExpandableListView. I display question as a text in GroupView and answer as a text in ChildView. If items can fit into screen, there's no problem, it works as it should. But when there's more items than the screen height and I have to scroll, this problem occurs that when I expand the last item, it acts like it's expanded but I can not scroll to the child view.

Any ideas or experiences on this issue?

Here's the screenshot (as you can see, scrollbar shows that it's expanded and there's place to scroll, but when I try to scroll, no luck) :

[image: SS]

**EDIT:** I found out that this problem is because I'm using a WebView inside child row, when I switched to TextView it works as expected. How can I achieve the same result with WebView?

Comment: try setting your webview to focusable=false..\ clickable=false i suspect that it hijacks the scroll gesture from the list view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your getGroupView() method of BaseExpandableListAdapter, give view=null as the first line of the method.

Comment: Hi @Yasin did this solve your problem?
I have the same issue but and `view = null` did not solve the problem. Wouldn't `view = null` just force the adapter not to reuse the view?